# Oauth2 authentication with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Hi I am really new to Spring boot and Oauth2. I need to understand how to authenticate Spring boot web service with Oauth2 authentication with refresh token and access tokens. Likewise I need to know how to limit the access of different users (accessing resources) dynamically as well. I have searched in many articles on line and ended up with nothing that I really need to learn. I do not need SSO config with facebook or google. I want to know how to make our own authorization server.

Can anybody please help me to guide or send me a link of a useful tutorial that helps me to learn.

thank you.

Comment: This is an open-ended question. You can start with [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) famous tutorial by Dave Syer

Comment: No. that is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question. So few links to start with:

Ok, start with [OAuth2 Guide](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) then [OAuth2 Grant types](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/). These are generic stuff you need to know.

Then In [Spring Security OAuth 2 using Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2) .

You can basically restrict the API access in Resource Server by using a combination of OAuth scopes and Roles.

And finally, [this](https://github.com/FrontierPsychiatrist/spring-oauth-example) is an amazing example which shows you how to manage OAuth clients, their grant types, tokens and so on.

Please get back with specific queries, it would be easier to help.